# javafx how to plot a chart in real time

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to plot a chart in real time to create an illustration of the trajectory of a projectile and simulate how it moves through the air. However, when I try to do this, nothing is plotted on the chart but no errors are thrown.

```
    String seriesName = " ";
    fireButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        double initialVelValue = initialVelSlider.getValue();
        double angleValue = angleSlider.getValue();
        double gravityValue = gravitySlider.getValue();
        // Define series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName(seriesName);     // Title of the series
        graph.setLegendVisible(false);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                double elapsedTime = (now - startTime)/1000000000d;
                updateGraph(graph, initialVelValue, angleValue, gravityValue, 0, 
                        projectileCalculations.getTotalDisplacement(initialVelValue, angleValue, gravityValue),
                        " ", elapsedTime);

                System.out.println(elapsedTime);
                if(elapsedTime > projectileCalculations.getTotalTime(initialVelValue, angleValue, gravityValue)) {
                    this.stop();
                }
            }
        }.start();

public void updateGraph(LineChart chart, double initialVel, double angle, double gravity, double start, double stop, String seriesName, double elapsedTime){
    double step = (stop-start) / 100; // Divide the visible area into 1000 parts

    int vMax = 0;
    double vDisplacement = projectileCalculations.getVDisplacement(initialVel, angle, gravity, elapsedTime);
    double hDisplacement = projectileCalculations.getHDisplacement(initialVel, angle, elapsedTime);
    vMax = (int) (vDisplacement > vMax ? Math.ceil(vDisplacement) : vMax);



    XYChart.Series series;
    boolean newChart = false;
    if (chart.getData().size() > 0) {
        newChart = true;
        series = (XYChart.Series) chart.getData().get(0);
    } else {
        series = new Series();
    }

    series.getData().clear();
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(hDisplacement, vDisplacement));


    ((NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis()).setAutoRanging(false); // Alow manual choosing of range
    ((NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis()).setLowerBound(0); // Set start and stop of axis
    ((NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis()).setUpperBound(vMax);


    if (newChart) {
        chart.getData().add(series); // Add data series to line chart
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are exactly trying to do, but since `chart.getData()` starts empty `newChart` is false and no series gets added to chart data.

I would simplify this to work with just 1 series first the tackle the problem of painting more then 1 series.

Comment: However, after adding your suggestion it now throws an error saying "duplicate series added"... any suggestions?

Comment: Add the series outside updateGraph, inside your updateGraph method you just pick the current series and add data to it.

Comment: The only problem is when I do this, I then need to parse in LineChart chart and Series seriesName into the getScene() function which is run in the main menu, thus needing to pass it in to start() which cant be done